# How do I add Hive support in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hive-metastore

I've got the following set-up:
- HDFS
- Hive
- Remote Hive Metastore (and a metastore db)
- Apache Spark (downloaded and installed from https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.3/)

I can use Hive as expected, create tables - read data from HDFS and all that. But, cannot get spark to run with Hive Support. Whenever I run `val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("MyApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()`

I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.`

Hive classes are in the path, and I have copied over hive-site.xml, core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml

Do I need to build spark with hive support (as mentioned here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-hive-and-jdbc-support) to get spark to work with hive?

Is there a Spark with Hive support tar available which I can extract instead of building from source?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What environment are you running spark in?  The easy answer is to let whatever packaging tool is available do all the heavy lifting.  For example if you're on osx use brew to install everything.  If you're in a maven/sbt project bring in the spark-hive package, etc.

> Do I need to build spark with hive support

If you're manually building spark from source yes you do.  Here's an example command.  (but chances are you don't have todo this)

> ./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-hive-and-jdbc-support

If you're missing class,spark is internally checking for the pressence of "org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf" which is in the hive-exec-1.2.1.spark.jar.  Note this is a customized version of hive designed to work nicely with spark.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spark-project.hive/hive-exec/1.2.1.spark

Comment: Thanks for the response @Andrew Long, I'm installing and building Spark in a container using docker. Its based on debian:stretch image - so getting the tar from https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.3/ and using tar to extract the source code. Looks like I'll have to build from source anyway!

Comment: Is there a tar available which is built with Hive Support?

Comment: added an update with the exact jar you need.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! I *think* this is what I was looking for. That said, In the meanwhile I started looking into just building spark from the source. I'll try adding the JAR you mentioned first.

Comment: using that Jar didn't work. I'm guessing i'll have to build it from source with hive support

Comment: Any idea where to find the source code @AndrewLong ?